# jQuery поиск children после одиночных тегов

Tags: jquery

Простой пример, если попадаются одиночные блоки вроде **hr**, то последующие элементы не находит. jQuery 3.2.1

```html
<p>Some text <hr> some <b>text</b>!!!!</p>
```

```js
console.log($('div').children().length) // = 0
```

UPD: поправил по просьбам

Comment: Не знаю, у меня находит 2 - https://jsfiddle.net/y7m7w2qp/

Comment: только что тоже на филде попробовал, тоже 2, а просто в браузере на html страничке не хочет

Comment: попробовал на html-страничке - тоже всё ок. может, у Вас jQuery криво подключается. попробуйте <script src="https : // code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> (пробелы только лишние поубирайте)

Comment: я так же подключал только 3 версию, да с разными версиями та же петрушка

Comment: Нашел причину, у себя проверял на теге p, и браузер занимался самовалидацией html и в итоге разбил тег на 2 с hr и b по отдельности. Оно и понятно, оказывается так и должно быть In the DOM, the opening tag on a block-level element will close the <p> element.

Comment: @rodigy если вы замените пример в тексте вопроса, можно было бы написать полноценный ответ и спасти вопрос от закрытия)

Comment: @andreymal , а какая разница? решение найдено, и совсем не связанное с jq

Comment: @rodigy ну пригодится же другим людям, которые тоже будут пихать `hr` внутрь `p` :)

Comment: @rodigy, мне редактор даже подсвечивает красным, мол, нельзя внутри p вставлять hr. Так что править вопрос смысла не было - проблема ведь не в том, что jQuery не находит children, а банально в невалидной разметке

Comment: @humster_spb так и я говорил что не было

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `<p>` — это такой особенный тег, который не требует обязательного явного закрытия и который может неявно закрываться одним из следующих тегов (список взял из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)):

`<address>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<fieldset>`, `<footer>`, `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<hr>`, `<menu>`, `<nav>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`, `<section>`, `<table>`, `<ul>` или ещё один `<p>`

Таким образом, структура вида:

```
<p>Что-то<hr>что-то ещё</p>
```

парсится в такой вид:

```
<p>Что-то</p>
<hr/>
что-то ещё
<p></p>
```

Кстати, из-за того, что последний `</p>` по сути закрывает ранее не открытый тег, код является невалидным, а браузеры в конце добавляют пустой `<p></p>`, пытаясь таким образом исправить ошибку.

Если вы хотите получать все эти внутренности, можно, к примеру, обернуть всё это дело в `<div>`, который никогда неявно не закрывается (данный код является валидным):

```js
console.log(
    document.querySelector('div').children.length
);

// И для наглядности посмотрим, как браузер распарсил html-код:
console.log(document.querySelector('div').outerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
   <p>Some text <hr> some <b>text</b>!!!!
</div>
```

Если же вам принципиально завернуть всё в `<p>`, то придётся писать код вроде `<p>Some text</p><hr><p>some <b>text</b>!!!!</p>`